# Why might one add ~/.profile to ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: profile

When installing [RVM](https://rvm.io/) the one gets the following message:

```
* WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
  to do that add the following line to '/home/dotancohen/.bash_profile':

    source ~/.profile
```

I'm concerned because my ~/.profile file contains `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` which I obviously don't want to run (swapping my CapsLock and ESC keys) every time I open a new shell.

**Why might the wise RVM devs suggest sourcing `.profile` in `.bash_profile`?**

Comment: i guess the rvm guys don't know how shell profiles are supposed to work. they've got it ass-backwards. *(but so does `bash` generally, too)*. `~/.profile:/etc/profile` is sourced at login by login shells *(provided they are not profile shells - which have different profiles)* and environment files *(.rcs)* are sourced by any new interactive shell *(though its supposed to be done for the value of `$ENV`, really)*. you've got it right, though. nevermind, that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.profile` and `.bash_profile` are identical in terms of when they're meant to be executed: they're executed when you log in. The difference is that only bash runs `.bash_profile`; Bourne-style shells (dash, ksh, etc.) runs `.profile`. Bash itself runs `.profile` if `.bash_profile` doesn't exist.

Even if you have bash as your login shell, `.profile` is often the one that's executed when you log in in graphical mode — many distributions set up the X session startup script to run under `sh` and load `.profile`.

Hence the advice to use `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile` to do things like defining environment variables. Unless you absolutely need bash-specific features, just put everything in `.profile`. But even if you do, there's a reason to keep a `.bash_profile`, which is that when bash loads it, it doesn't load `.bashrc`, even if it's interactive. Hence, for most people, `~/.bash_profile` should consist of these two lines:

```
. ~/.profile
case  $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

You should not run `xmodmap` from `.profile`. This isn't executed when you open a new shell, but it is executed, for example, when you log in remotely with SSH with X11 forwarding. Unfortunately, there's no standard file that's loaded when you log in in graphical mode. Debian loads `~/.xsessionrc` (I think this applies to all display managers, except Gdm which loads `~/.xprofile` instead); other distributions have different setups. If you need cross-distribution portability, it may be easier to configure your desktop environment to execute `xmodmap` when it starts. If all you're doing is swapping CapsLock and Ctrl, this can be done with XKB settings that most modern desktop environments provide an interface to.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that Ubuntu 15.10 (with Unity) does not run even `~/.xsessionrc` on graphical login. That's just for your information, according to the fine intercords, there doesn't seem to be _any_ file that is loaded on graphical login.

Comment: @dotancohen Funny, I do see the loading of `.xsessionrc` in the scripts even on Ubuntu 15.10. Oh, looks like [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/475529). With gdm, you need to use `~/.xprofile`.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that bash(1) is the only shell that reads `.bash_profile`, other Bourne shell derivatives just read `.profile`. If you sometimes use another shell, you'd want to keep `.profile`.